# Adding category in wordpress - custom

Tags: php, posts

```
// Auto post ( Unique File Date ).
$postData = array(
    'post_category' => array( '0' ),
    'post_status' => $Post_Status,
    'post_type' => $Post_Type,
    'post_date' => $File_Individual_Date
);
wp_insert_post( $postData );
```

when using `'post_category' => array( '0' ),`, it adds a post under the category `Uncategorised`. What if I have a category in a var lets say:

`$myCategory = 'News'`;

then using `'post_category' => $myCategory` gives error and no new post is added. Is it possible to add categories in this way?

Comment: Have you tried lowercase `news`? Or the ID of the category?

Comment: i tried in lowercase but that didn't help too. how do i use the id? News category is creating on the runtime.

Comment: Try `$myCategory = array( 'news' );`